# Failure/Error FactoryGirl.create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm having trouble making multiple factories of the same class in factorygirl.

I've got 4 models

- aaa has bbbs & cccs
- bbb belongs to aaa & has ddds
- ccc belongs to aaa & has ddds
- ddd belongs to bbb & ccc

Here are my factoies

*aaas.rb*

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :aaa do
    after(:create) do |aaa|
      create_list(:bbb_a, 1, aaa: aaa)
      create_list(:ccc_a, 1, aaa: aaa)
    end
  end
end
```

*bbbs.rb*

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :bbb do
    factory :bbb_a do
       ddd_a
    end
  end
end
```

*cccs.rb*

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :ccc do
    factory :ccc_a do
      ddd_a
    end
  end
end
```

*ddds.rb*

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :ddd do
    factory :ddd_a do
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the test I'm running to get the error

*aaa_spec.rb*

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe Aaa do
  it "works" do
    aaa = FactoryGirl.create(:aaa)
    puts aaa
    puts aaa.bbbs 
    puts aaa.cccs
    aaa.bbbs.each {|bbb| puts bbb.ddd}
    aaa.cccs.each {|ccc| puts ccc.ddd}
  end
end
```

I had bbb_b, bbb_c, ccc_b, ccc_c, ddd_b, and ddd_c in there too, but they are not needed to get the error.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Not so much an error than it is just not loading. If I try to print BBB CCC or DDD out, I will print out nothing.

Answer (score 0):

*aaas.rb*

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :aaa do
    after(:build) do |aaa|
      aaa.bbbs << build(:bbb_a)
      aaa.cccs << build(:ccc_a)
    end
  end
end
```

*bbbs.rb*

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :bbb do
    factory :bbb_a do
      after(:build) do |bbb|
        bbb.ddd = ddd_a
      end
    end
  end
end
```

*cccs.rb*

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :ccc do
    factory :ccc_a do
      after(:build) do |ccc|
        ccc.ddd = ddd_a
      end
    end
  end
end
```